# Clojure: how to get from a map using a string key

Tags: dictionary, clojure, key, clojurescript

If I have a map like this:

```
(def foo {:bar "foobar"})
```

And I've been passed the key `:bar` as a string (i.e. `":bar"`)
I want to be able to access the value from the map doing something like

```
(get foo (symbol ":bar"))
```

which I thought would work, because `(symbol ":bar")` is `:bar` ... but it just returns `nil`

Comment: shouldn't that be `(keyword "bar")` instead?

Comment: well yes, (keyword "bar") works ... but I have `":bar"` in the string not `"bar"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to make from string ":asd" a keyword `:asd` you do something like this:

```
> (= (read-string ":asd") (keyword (subs ":asd" 1)) :asd)
true
```

Your code with `(symbol ":asd")` just print itself like `:asd` but is actually a symbol, not keyword.

Comment: thanks for that ... it feels a bit hacky to wrangle the string first, but looks like that's the only way.

Comment: It is a bit hacky, because you have the string `":asd"` to begin with. Where did that string come from? More likely, you can address this problem closer to its source, by generating a more reasonable string input in the first place.

Comment: yeah I ended up doing just that ... I used `(name ":asd")` before it got stored ... so I could just used `(keyword "asd")` on the string. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

If your string really is ":bar", just do a replace to remove the colon and then use `keyword` to convert it to a keyword.

`(def foo {:bar "foobar"})`

`(foo (keyword (clojure.string/replace ":bar" #"\:" "")))` => "foobar"

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
((read-string ":bar") {:bar "foobar"})
=> "foobar"
```

Or of course:

```
(get {:bar "foobar"} (read-string ":bar"))
```